# How to make a scrolling bar

Tags: html, css

Hey i am trying to make a dropdown men with a scrolling bar but i cant find out how i have to do it.

This is my code

```html
<h2>Uren invullen</h2>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Begintijd</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content" size="6">
    <a href="#">0</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
    <a href="#">9</a>
    <a href="#">10</a>
    <a href="#">11</a>
    <a href="#">12</a>
    <a href="#">13</a>
    <a href="#">14</a>
    <a href="#">15</a>
    <a href="#">16</a>
    <a href="#">17</a>
    <a href="#">18</a>
    <a href="#">19</a>
    <a href="#">20</a>
    <a href="#">21</a>
    <a href="#">22</a>
    <a href="#">23</a>
    <a href="#">24</a> 

  </div>
</div>
```

And i want to make a scrolling bar so i wont have to see all the options at once but i cant figure out how i should do it do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

simply Give fixed height to dropdown menu like below code

```
.dropdown-content
{
height:200px;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: max-height would be better in case the dropdown is lower that 200px.